# Where is wine1.7-dev in 14.04

Tags: wine, shared-library

In Ubuntu 14.04 I can find these packages:

```
wine1.4, wine1.6, wine1.7
```

and also:

```
wine1.4-dev, wine1.6-dev
```

Now where is  **wine1.7-dev**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wine1.7 has not yet been packaged into the stable release of ubuntu, so you won't find wine1.7 in your system if you don't have wine ppa's enabled. To get wine1.7 using the ppa, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then enter the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

and then update the package list using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then you will find wine1.7 and wine1.7-dev to be installable using:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Note that this will upgrade wine if it is already installed, otherwise install.

The list of packages that are available for installation on a default ubuntu, without ppa's can be seen [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Great answer. But I don't find wine1.7 on my system. But I just noticed that it is not even released as stable yet. Is any way to check if a fresh Ubuntu installation comes with wine1.7 in the repositories?

Comment: @Tarrasch: Turns out I had a wine ppa in my system which showed the 1.7. Modified my answer to reflect how to get wine1.7 and to check how to get the packages that are available for installation on a default system.